# How to correct myself orally

Tags: word-usage

I sometimes say something wrong in English and I figure out myself it was wrong or I can guess from people's reaction.

If I want to ask them what's the correct way to say it, is it ok to say:

> Should I have say "fixed sentenced" instead ?

Example:

> Me: What time have it ?
>
> My friend: ...oh 4pm!
>
> Me: Should I have say "What time is it?" instead

Comment: There are many options. Similar to yours, "Should I have *said* 'What time is it?'" or if you don't want to guess, simply "What is *the correct/the best/a better* way to say that?"

Comment: With your version it should be *Should I have **said**...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is in the past (you've already asked), you would say,

> "Should I have said, 'What time is it?' instead?"

If it were in the future (you're about to ask), you would say,

> "Should I say, 'What time is it?' instead?"

But don't mix the two. "Should I have say" is not correct.